# Standart window title buttons style - Close and Minimize

Tags: qt, qml

I need to make buttons that look like standard window title buttons with their icons (close/minimize) in the current operating system (win / osx / linux). Is there a possibility in qml?

Answer (score 0):

You take screenshots (or google for images) of those buttons in their different states (enabled, pressed, highlighted, normal e.t.c), than you style your `Button`s to show the right image at the right time.

Which set you need to choose, depends on the OS, which you can query with

[`Qt.platform.os`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#platform-prop)

Depending on the usecase, it might be worth to investigate the possibility to use *real* `Window`s, if you are planning on building some kind of *subwindows*. Might prove complicated, though.